# Custom Orderby/ThenBy

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if this is possible, I'm trying to order/sort/rearrange  a data:

```
  TYPE    NAME   CODE
     1     AAA      7
     1     BBB      8  
     5     CCC      6
     4     DDD      5
     1     EEE      7
     1     DDD      8
```

into like this:

```
  TYPE    NAME   CODE
     1     AAA      7
     1     EEE      7
     4     BBB      1
     5     CCC      6
     1     BBB      8 
     1     DDD      8
```

sorted by type then by name, but if code  = 8 then it should be at last.

code:

```
 SomeList.OrderBy(c => c.Type).
  ThenBy(c => c.Name).
  ThenBy(c => Code);
```

Comment: Make an array like : int[] sortArray = {7,1,6,8};  Then use dt.OrderBy(x => sortArray.IndexOf(x.Code))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this "conditional sorting". It's important that the code check comes first:

```
var query = SomeList
    .OrderBy(c => c.Code == 8 ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Type)
    .ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: thank you so much it  worked! I applied it to my code (applied it to Then By)

Comment: would like to ask, although it works I would like to understand it, correctly.If its true then it  would order by desc?(1?) and if its false (0)  asc?

Comment: @JaneOrtega: Yes, the question mark is the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). If the condition is `true` it takes the first value(1) otherwise the second(0). Since `OrderBy` is ascending (as opposed to `OrderByDescending`) it will take lower values first and 0 is lower than 1 which means all items with `c.Code == 8` come last. This `OrderBy(condition)` basically splits all items into two groups.